# Correct Syntax for a TSQL query to Compare Dates

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I am looking for the correct syntax to test in a TSQL WHERE clause if a 
datetime2(7) type is equal to another.

```
WHERE (CAST(modifiedDate AS DATETIME) = '9/29/2016 3:24:24 PM')
```

I also tried

```
WHERE (CAST(modifiedDate AS DATETIME) LIKE '9/29/2016 3:24:24 PM')
```

And

```
WHERE (CAST(modifiedDate AS datetime2) = CAST('09/29/2016 3:24:24 PM' AS datetime2))
```

I believe I have the right hand side stated incorrectly, but that is the exact value in the database.

I am looking for all records that match that datetimestamp.

To be clear I did try to search for other results..'

[image]

I thought this was a little flaky for a search result on this site.

DB field type...

[image]

Comment: casting to datetime will give you milleseconds as well. So the above will not work. Try comparing using milliseconds also OR do a range check within that second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare DATETIME values, you need DATETIME values to compare. You can use the TSQL `CONVERT` function to convert a string to the DATETIME datatype. For example:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-09-28 15:34:00', 20)
```

Note that the third argument is the "style". Example above uses style 20, the ODBC Canonical style YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS (24 hour clock). There are several other styles available, maybe you find one that matches your string format. (If you can't find a match, then you will need to use some string manipulation functions to reformat your string into a format where a style is available.)

As the second argument, you can use a string literal (as shown in the example above), or you can use a reference to a CHAR or VARCHAR column.

Reference: [**CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

---

On a different, but related, note: Why are date time values being stored as strings in the database, and not DATETIME datatype?

---

If the datatype of the column is `DATETIME2(7)`, then I think you would want to compare `DATETIME2(7)` datatypes.

If we do an "equal to" comparison, that's going to be an *exact* match, including the fractional seconds.  If you want to match DATETIME2(7) values from a given second, you could use a range comparison:

```
  WHERE t.my_col_datetime2_7  >= '2016-09-29 15:24:24'
    AND t.my_col_datetime2_7  <  '2016-09-29 15:24:25'
```

Note the format of the string literals allowed for comparison to DATETIME2 are `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` (24 hour clock) with optional fractional seconds `.nnnnnnn`.

Reference: [**Supported String Literal Formats for datetime2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql)

Comment: They are being stored as datetime2(7)

Comment: This does not work either....WHERE        (CONVERT(DATETIME, modifiedDate, 20) = CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/29/2016 3:24:24 PM', 20))

Comment: reviewing your links

Comment: There's no need to CAST or CONVERT a column value that is already a DATETIME or DATETIME2 into a different datatype. You want the literal (on the right side) to match the datatype of the column, so no conversion of the column is necessary. Comparison to the raw column makes it possible for SQL Server to make effective use an index; wrapping the column in a function prevents SQL Server from effectively using an index.

Comment: Got it, thank you, this worked, and I understand about the CAST compare, I had been trying a number of types, including just casting both as DATE which worked then adding an AND condition to parse the TIME values. Couldn't get that either, but this is working.

Comment: As quick note, I did want to do an exact compare, but it does not work with just =.  WHERE  (modifiedDate = '2016-09-29 15:24:24') returns no results. there are about 140000 records time stamped with the exact time '09/29/2016 3:24:24 PM' so an exact match is my preference. Other wise, I will need to increment the seconds to create the range.

Comment: `WHERE modifieddate = '2016-09-29 15:24:24'` would "work", in that it the comparison would evaluate  to true for rows that have (datetime2(7))  `modifieddate` value of exactly `'2016-09-29 15:24:24.0000000'`. The comparison would yield false for any values with fractional seconds other than 0, e.g. `'2016-09-29 15:24:24.56789'`. And a similar issue if you wanted to return values "equal to" a given minute. And that's why the normative pattern is to use *range comparisons* for datetime.

Comment: The records are inserted with the exact same seconds value '09/29/2016 3:24:24 PM', all 140000, but the = comparison will not return any records. So if I understand you, the equate requires .000 milliseconds, and because I do not know what the fractional seconds are on these records, if they are not equal to .000 they return false on the match test?

Comment: Yes. Just as a datetime value of `'2016-09-29 15:55:24'` is *not* equal to a date literal without a time component `'2016-09-29'`. It's also *not* equal to datetime literal with a resolution of minutes (no seconds) `'2016-09-29 15:55'`. The usual behavior when seconds and fractional seconds are omitted on the literal is to assume zeros. Just as the usual behavior when omitting time components is to assume midnight (zeros for time components... `'00:00:00.000'`. The `datetime2(7)` datatype has resolution down to 100 nanoseconds... fractional seconds up to 7 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are having issues.  I guess it depends how you are storing your date value.  If it's datetime2, this works fine.

```
DECLARE @testtable TABLE(
ID INT
, modifieddate DATETIME2)

INSERT INTO @testtable 
(id, modifieddate)
VALUES 

(1, '9/29/2016 3:24:24 PM'),
(2, '2/01/2016 3:24:24 PM'),
(3, '6/25/2016 3:24:24 PM')



SELECT * 
FROM @testtable 

SELECT * 
FROM @testtable 
WHERE CAST(modifieddate AS DATETIME2) = '09/29/2016 3:24:24 PM'

SELECT * 
FROM @testtable 
WHERE modifieddate = '9/29/2016 3:24:24 PM'

SELECT * 
FROM @testtable 
WHERE modifieddate = CAST('09/29/2016 3:24:24 PM' AS DATETIME2)
```

Comment: My date field has values like these = '9/29/2016 3:24:24 PM'

Comment: No milliseconds

Comment: Updated.  That should work fine if you are storing as varchar.

Comment: As a side note, pretty sure '9/29/2016 3:24:24 PM' is not a datetime2(7) value.